# Error in getting the array out of JSON string

Tags: c++, json, libjson

I am trying to get the array from my JSON Stinrg defined in the main function. I have used libjson API for this, simple key value is easy to get so I am able to get the value of RootA but how about this array in ChildA. Please let me know

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libjson/libjson.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

char rootA[20];
int childB;
int *childInt;

void ParseJSON(JSONNODE *n) {
    if (n == NULL) {
        printf("Invalid JSON Node\n");
        return;
    }

    JSONNODE_ITERATOR i = json_begin(n);
    while (i != json_end(n)) {
        if (*i == NULL) {
            printf("Invalid JSON Node\n");
            return;
        }

        // recursively call ourselves to dig deeper into the tree
        if (json_type(*i) == JSON_ARRAY || json_type(*i) == JSON_NODE) {
            ParseJSON(*i);
        }

        // get the node name and value as a string
        json_char *node_name = json_name(*i);

        // find out where to store the values
        if (strcmp(node_name, "RootA") == 0) {
            json_char *node_value = json_as_string(*i);
            strcpy(rootA, node_value);
            cout << rootA<<"\n";
            json_free(node_value);
        } else if (strcmp(node_name, "ChildA") == 0) {
            JSONNODE *node_value = json_as_array(*i);

            childInt=reinterpret_cast<int *>(&node_value);
            cout << childInt[0]<<"\n";
            cout << childInt[1]<<"\n";
            json_free(node_value);
        } else if (strcmp(node_name, "ChildB") == 0) {
            childB = json_as_int(*i);
            cout << childB;
        }
        // cleanup and increment the iterator
        json_free(node_name);
        ++i;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char
            *json =
                    "{\"RootA\":\"Value in parent node\",\"ChildNode\":{\"ChildA\":[1,2],\"ChildB\":42}}";
    JSONNODE *n = json_parse(json);
    ParseJSON(n);
    json_delete(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks not-sehe but I got the solution for this

Ok I got it... treat array as a node and iterate over it again as if its a value with blank key. You can see the code part which did it..

```
if (json_type(*i) == JSON_ARRAY) {
    cout << "\n Its a Json Array";
    JSONNODE *arrayValue = json_as_array(*i);
    JSONNODE_ITERATOR i1 = json_begin(arrayValue);
    while (i1 != json_end(arrayValue)) {
            cout << "\n In Array Loop ";
        cout << json_as_int(*i1);
        ++i1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you were looking for, but let me just demonstrate that a library with a slightly more modern interface makes this a lot easier ([test.cpp](https://github.com/sehe/spirit-v2-json/blob/q17064905/test.cpp)):

```
#include <sstream>
#include "JSON.hpp"

int main()
{
    auto document = JSON::readFrom(std::istringstream(
                "{\"RootA\":\"Value in parent node\",\"ChildNode\":{\"ChildA\":[1,2],\"ChildB\":42}}"));

    auto childA = as_object(
                as_object(document)[L"ChildNode"]
            )[L"ChildA"];

    std::cout << childA << std::endl;
}
```

Which prints

```
[1,2]
```

It's using my own minimalist implementation of the [rfc4627 specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627). It's minimalist in interface only, supporting the full syntax and UNICODE.

The API interface is quite limited, but you can already see that working without C-style pointers, with proper dictionary lookups, key comparisons etc. makes it a less tedious and error prone:

```
// or use each value
for(auto& value : as_array(childA).values)
    std::cout << value << std::endl;

// more advanced:
JSON::Value expected = JSON::Object {
    { L"RootA", L"Value in parent node" },
    { L"ChildNode", JSON::Object {
             { L"ChildA", JSON::Array { 1,2 } },
             { L"ChildB", 42 },
         } },
};
std::cout << "Check equality: " << std::boolalpha << (document == expected) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Serialized: " << document;
```

See the full parser implementation (note: it includes serialization too) at github: https://github.com/sehe/spirit-v2-json/tree/q17064905